# Issues with assigning result of a function to a variable

Tags: c++, size

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string userInput;
   int stringSize = 0;

   userInput = "Hello";

   userInput.size() == stringSize;

   cout << "Size of userInput: " << stringSize << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I am trying to get an output of 5, but it is returning 0. I can't figure out what's wrong. The `userInput` "Hello" should have a size of 5 and `userInput.size()` should return 5. This should be assigned to variable stringSize. Side note, can anyone explain to me why it is "==" not "="? If I try it with "=", it does not compile and I get this error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:23: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    userInput.size() = stringSize;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

My understanding is "=" is assignment and "==" is a Boolean comparison that is either "true" or "false" depending on if both sides are equal. I am trying to assign the size of `userInput.size()` into the variable so I would think that I should use "=". Maybe this is part of the problem?

Comment: You're right to use a single equals sign. It's clear you know how to order variables for assignment. left side is the what you want to assign a value to, and right side of the equals sign is the value you want to assign to it. P.S. this should be tagged as C++

Comment: so what does the error mean? i fixed the tag also :)

Comment: you cannot write `5 = variable`. If you want to assign a value to some variable, the variable **must** be on the **left side*** of the assignment. `variable = 5` . I used this simplification, but the result of the function size() is like the 5 in my example. You cannot "set the size" by assigning something to `size()`, if that was your intent. The result of this function is just an `int` value, a 'R-Value', that you can use only on the right side of an assignment.

Comment: @Pac0, you should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: The `std::string::size()` returns a constant.  Essentially you can't set the size of a string; the `std::string` class will calculate it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer that was asked for (credits to PacO ):

You always have to put the value that you want to assign to the variable on the right side of the `=`-operator, and the variable itself to the left side.

What you did, is trying to assign the value of `stringSize` to `userInput.size()`

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is "=" is assignment and "==" is a boolean comparison
>   that is either "true" or "false" depending on if both sides are equal.

Your understanding is correct so far.

> I am trying to assign the size of userInput.size() into the variable
>   so I would think that I should use "="

In general, you cannot write `5 = variable`. **Left and right in an assignment are not swappable**, the order matters.

If you want to assign a value to some variable, the variable must be on the **left side** of the assignment :  `variable = 5` .

I used this simplification, but the result of the function size() is like the 5 in my example. This is called a *rvalue* (like "right-value").

So, in your case, `stringSize = userInput.size();` would be correct and set the size of `userInput` into the variable `stringSize` (which is called a *lvalue* a value that can be assigned to, at the left of an assignment).

Answer (score 1):

An lvalue can be seen as a named value that exists past its use, such as a variable. An rvalue doesn't persist past its use, usually the result of a function call or what we'd often refer to as simply a "value".

You can store an rvalue in an lvalue (`int i = 2 + 3`), but you can't assign an lvalue to an rvalue. That's where your problem exists

The compiler is throwing an error because you have an rvalue `userInput.size()` and you're treating it as if it's an lvalue by attempting to assign a value to it.

```
userInput.size() = stringSize
```

A simpler example would be

```
int n = 1;
3 = n;
```

For obvious reasons, you can't just change what 3 is. In your example your function is just returning an integer value...so why should you be able to change that? So you get an error

Answer (score 0):

A different perspective:

You can't set the size of a string.  The `std::string` class automatically calculates the length for you.

So there is no need for the expression:

```
userInput.size() = stringSize;
```

To clear the contents of a `std::string`, use the `clear()` method:

```
userInput.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

> `=`  is an Assignment Operator in C, C++ and other programming languages.
>
> `==` is assigns the value of right side expression’s or variable’s
>   value to the left side variable.

Simple example:

```
int x,y;
x=10;
y=10;

if(x==y)
    printf("True");
else
    printf("False");
```

output will be : `True`

In your case, you have to use one `=` operator and put function assignment on right of the variable. like this `stringSize = userInput.size();`

This is the final code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userInput;
   int stringSize = 0;

   userInput = "Hello";

    stringSize = userInput.size(); //this line edited.

   cout << "Size of userInput: " << stringSize << endl;

   return 0;

}
```

see here [online_c++_compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/BkHASkDgM)